# Yii framework and PostgreSQL partitioned table - 0 rows affected

Tags: postgresql, triggers, yii, partitioning

- PostgreSQL 9.1
- Partitioned tables

  - tbl_master
  - tbl_slave1 (iherits master)
  - tbl_slave2 (iherits master)
- Yii framework 1.1.10

Maybe someone can chare his expierience about Yii + PostgreSQL partitioned table.
PostgreSQL part with partitioned tables, checks and triggers works great but i can't get Yii to *love* these tables..

Problem is that on insert into partitioned table PostgreSQL gives `0 rows affected` and i can't figure out how to workaround this.
Yii model thinks new record is not saved (but it is) and `$Model->save();` return false and so `afterSave()` is not working and so on.

All other methods as `->find()` or `->findAll()` are working well. Even if i update just now saved record throw yii all is ok and i get executed `afterSave` as well. Problem is only with `->save()` part.
*Update working because i have trigger only on inserting new rows*.

I'm using trigger to split new data by tables. Maybe i need to modify trigger so postgres know what i'm forwarding new data to `slave` table not `master`?

One more thing. I added primary key to `master` table so Yii Model (CActiveRecord) don't throw errors about table without pk. I know documentation does not suggest this, but i got it working this way. Just trying to give *big picture* of my situation.

Thanks!

Comment: Not so pretty workaround: Use `RETURN NEW;` in trigger instead of `RETURN NULL;`. And now i have two identical rows - one in `master` and second in `slave` table. So i need to add trigger `AFTER INSERT` to clear `master` table (`DELETE FROM ONLY master`). *Thinking out loud..* - but it would work.

Comment: **Confirming** previous comment - it's working. For now it is good workaround.

Answer (score 2):

You could try using rules as an alternative. As it rewrites the query I would expect it to return the correct number of affected rows. While triggers are in most cases better I think rules are better then inserting data in the master table and having to delete it again.

This is covered in paragraph 5.9.5 on [this manual page](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/ddl-partitioning.html).